# Proper Guid Mapping. Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I use an abstract `Entity` class which contains a Guid:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public /*virtual*/ Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I also have a class like:

```
public class Post : Entity
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

How do I properly map `Post` class using xml-mapping? I'm asking about Id.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```xml
<id name="Id">
    <generator class="guid"/>
</id>
```

This will generate Guids on the client using the `Guid.NewGuid()` method.

Alternative generators are:

- guid.native - generates the Guids on the server side, e.g. using `NEWID()` on SQL server
- guid.comb - generates "sequential" Guids, which reduces index fragmentation.

I would recommend guid.comb for most applications that use Guid identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Asp.Net Core, with the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package, and FluentNhibernate as mapping strategy.
In my case it was giving some errors when trying to get the data. The errors stopped, after mapping the Guid column as follows:

```
        Id(x => x.Id, x =>
        {
            x.Generator(Generators.Guid);
            x.Type(NHibernateUtil.Guid);
            x.Column("ID");            
        });
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the database used is Oracle12c